# Can a loader of a binary fill a memory area?

Tags: c, elf, portable-executable

I'm doing some tests here on my machine, and I realized that when I do not initialize a variable, its value tends to be 0, but it is only initialized with 0, when the code is compiled to 64 bits, after some tests , I verified that it seems to be the loader of the binary that fills the memory address with value 0, not the compiler. I would like to confirm if it is actually loader that puts the value 0, grateful

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x; //section .bss

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Global variables (like `x` in your code) are guaranteed to be initialized with 0. How that happens is irrelevant, but sure, the loader does take care of that in some implementations.

Comment: *But it is only initialized with 0, when the code is compiled to 64 bits* -- I am curious to see the case where you find it *not* initialized to 0?

Comment: Oh yes, I was talking about local variable, which when I compiled to 32 bits was undefined behavior, but in 64 bits it was not.

Comment: "when I compiled to 32 bits was undefined behavior, but in 64 bits it was not." -- you are mistaken -- uninitialized local variable has undefined value in *both* 32 and 64-bit builds. It *just happened* to have value of 0 in a particular 64-bit build on a particular machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm doing some tests here on my machine, and I realized that when I do
>   not initialize a variable, its value tends to be 0,

If a variable with static storage duration (such as your `x`) is defined without an initializer, then its initial value is 0 (arithmetic types) or a null pointer (pointer types), or else it is an aggregate type and its members are initialized per these rules (recursively) or it is a union type and its first member is initialized per these rules.  This is specified by [paragraph 6.7.9/10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10) of the language standard, so in a conforming conforming implementation "tends to be" is too weak.

But note that this does not apply to automatic variables (those declared at block scope and without a storage class specifier).  If an automatic variable is declared without an initializer then its initial value is indeterminate, and if you use such an object's value without first setting it then the behavior is undefined.  Perhaps this is why you hedged.

> but it is only
>   initialized with 0, when the code is compiled to 64 bits,

If we're talking about conforming implementations, then the target architecture's word size has nothing to do with it.

> after some
>   tests , I verified that it seems to be the loader of the binary that
>   fills the memory address with value 0, not the compiler.

That's implementation dependent.  C does not specify.  However, you tagged ELF, and C implementations that target ELF generally assign default-initialized objects to the BSS section, which is pretty much designed for the purpose.  BSS takes up no space on disk but when loaded it is initialized to all-bits-zero.

> I would like
>   to confirm if it is actually loader that puts the value 0, grateful

The program loader, whatever form that takes in any given implementation, sets the initial value of every variable with static duration, regardless of whether it is defined with an initializer.  It may do that by loading the value from disk or, in some cases, by zero-filling it without loading a specific value from disk, or possibly by some other mechanism.  As already described, for variables assigned to the BSS section of an ELF object, the loader (dynamic linker in this case) zero-fills the representation.

Comment: Many thanks for the response John Bollinger. So if the variable is static it is guaranteed to be with the value zero, but if it is not, it can vary with the loader implementation, correct?

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque, no. There is no "but if it is no". It is guaranteed to be initialized to `0` by the standard. The loader is just one way to implement it. Some implementations could have it as a part of the binary of even some instructions might be inserted to set the value to 0. There is no implementation dependent behavior here.

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque, "static storage duration" refers to an object whose lifetime is the whole run of the program.  This is **any** variable declared at file scope (where the `static` keyword affects *linkage*, not storage duration) and any variable declared at block scope with a storage class specifier (either `static` or `extern`).  If such a variable is defined without an initializer -- which definition might, in some cases, be elsewhere -- then its initial value is zero.

Comment: Objects with automatic storage duration (local variables) and without an initializer have an indeterminate initial value.  Because examining such an initial value produces undefined behavior, it's not really useful to talk about what factors might cause it to appear one way or another.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh yeah, I understood, thanks again for the explanations, :)